# How to track which row update failed in batch update

Tags: ado.net, dataadapter, batch-updates, updatebatchsize

I'm using a try catch blocks to do a batch update using ADO.NET2.0, the UpdateBatchSize is set 500, I can often catch exceptions, but I don't know which row update failed, is there a way to get the actual failed row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event [RowUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d1wk41s.aspx) to get the reference of row:

```
yourAdapter.RowUpdated += OnRowUpdated;
```

Then:

```
protected static void OnRowUpdated(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Status == UpdateStatus.ErrorsOccurred)
    {
        // Reference to row which throws error
        var row = args.Row;

        row.RowError = args.Errors.Message;
        args.Status = UpdateStatus.SkipCurrentRow;

        // Do something more
    }
}
```