# Is it possible to get the values of a row when having constraints violation?

Tags: sql-server, debugging

While bulk inserting thousands of records I get exception with the message 'Foreign key constraint violation'.

Unfortunately message provides no clues to the records with bad data.

Are there any tricks which allow to get more detailed information about the problem? Otherwise debugging such issues is a real pain.

Comment: are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: You should not import the data directly to the target table. You should import the data into a staging table, then you can query for bad rows and insert only good rows.

Comment: It is also good practice to name your constraints so you can tell which foreign keys were violated.

Comment: @Aaron No, just bulk insert, plain ado.net

Comment: @Rumbleweed They are named. Better than nothing, but still not too much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could add a handler for the OnRowUpdated event, where you could check for an error and look at information about the specific row.

See this answer for an example as a starting point:
[How to track which row update failed in batch update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558354/how-to-track-which-row-update-failed-in-batch-update)

For SqlBulkCopy check out this CodeProject article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387465/Retrieving-failed-records-after-an-SqlBulkCopy-exc

Comment: Alas, SqlBulkCopy class does not provide this event.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Have you already checked out this guy's CodeProject article? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/387465/Retrieving-failed-records-after-an-SqlBulkCopy-exc

Comment: Really good and simple Idea. After you got an exception, it's better to sacrifice a bit of performance and repeat operation slowly gathering data which is needed for quicker isolation of the problem.